# Summarize/GroupBy Distinct in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a PowerBI file with CSV files as datasources.  I created a table in PowerBI that summarizes the fields of a CSV file, and added a PrioirtyGrp field with Name, ID and Priority concatenated to group by.

I haven't found a way that works to group the rows of a single table by the PriorityGrp value in each row.  If I have a data set such as:

[image]

I've been trying to summarize and group on the PriorityGrp field to get a resulting table of:

[image]

but no luck.  What I know of SQL and VBA hasn't been much help in getting my arms around DAX, and I'm planning on doing a course, but if anyone has syntax for a Summarize, GroupBy or some other statement that could help with this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Do you definitely want to do this with DAX or is doing it in the query editor before loading to your model preferable?

Comment: Thanks - I would definitely use the query editor if I can get it to work.  I was only trying DAX because I was having trouble getting right syntax in the editor.

Comment: The query editor has a pretty good GUI so you don't need to worry about syntax too much for this.

Comment: Will do - thanks for the follow up on it.